# Manipulating items in a list, saving selections after program has terminated

Tags: python-2.7

I have a code that has a list of things of various uses. I want the user to use something different every day. Once an element has been used, it goes into the "used" list. The code suggests elements from the "unused" list to the user and the user makes a decision about whether or not to use the item that day.

I want to make it so that the program "remembers" what is on each list. Currently, as soon as the user selects "yes" on an item, the program ends, and everything resets. I would like for the user to be able to log on the next day and have their selections saved somehow. How would you go about this?

```
import random

unused = ['a','b','c','d','e']
used = []

choice = "no"

while choice == "no":
    suggestion = random.choice(unworn)
    print "Would you like to use %s ?" % suggestion
    choice = raw_input("> ")

if choice == "yes":
    used.append(suggestion)
    unused.remove(suggestion)
    print "Great job!"
```

Comment: Use a database.

Comment: or a file which you read at start and write at end